# Retrieve Salesforce Daily Api Requests limit

Tags: api, soap, salesforce

Does anyone know how to retrieve the SFDC daily requests api limit through SOAP or REST ? I don't see any call for this. Currently I have to access this info at the Company Info page. I would like to retrieve this info at code level for batch processing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using custom code to workaround this:

```
WebService static string GetAPIUsage() {
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/00D20000000HsCQ');//use id of setup page
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    String result = pr.getContent().toString();
    Integer start_index = result.indexOf('API Requests, Last 24 Hours', 1) + 52;
    Integer end_index = result.indexOf('<', start_index);
    result = result.substring(start_index, end_index);
    result = result.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ');
    return result;     
}
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Łukasz

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Lukasz ! I'll play with this.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

This info was not exposed in the API.

As of Salesforce Spring '15 and REST API version 29.0, the /limits resource can be used to retrieve this info. https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/restapi

Also, the Sforce-Limit-Info header is returned with every REST response.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_api_usage.htm

Comment: Is it entirely unfeasible to count the number of requests you've made in a given 24 hour period on the client side? Not particularly elegant but sounds like it may be your only choice.

Comment: yea currently we have to monitor this api limit using SFDC alert system (ex: api approaching 80% limit). I wish SFDC implement such call in the api or if anyone know of any workaround would be nice to retrieve this info from code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used REST API. Choose an HTTP method GET to perform on the REST API service URI: "**/services/data/v31.0/limits**". It allows me to get DailyApiRequests data.

It returns:

`{
  "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances" : {
    "Remaining" : 200,
    "Max" : 200
  },
  "ConcurrentSyncReportRuns" : {
    "Remaining" : 20,
    "Max" : 20
  },
  "DailyApiRequests" : {
    "Remaining" : 14995,
    "Max" : 15000
  },
  "DailyAsyncApexExecutions" : {
    "Remaining" : 250000,
    "Max" : 250000
  },
  "DailyBulkApiRequests" : {
    "Remaining" : 5000,
    "Max" : 5000
  },
  "DailyStreamingApiEvents" : {
    "Remaining" : 10000,
    "Max" : 10000
  },
  "DailyWorkflowEmails" : {
    "Remaining" : 390,
    "Max" : 390
  },
  "DataStorageMB" : {
    "Remaining" : 5,
    "Max" : 5
  },
  "FileStorageMB" : {
    "Remaining" : 20,
    "Max" : 20
  },
  "HourlyAsyncReportRuns" : {
    "Remaining" : 1200,
    "Max" : 1200
  },
  "HourlyDashboardRefreshes" : {
    "Remaining" : 200,
    "Max" : 200
  },
  "HourlyDashboardResults" : {
    "Remaining" : 5000,
    "Max" : 5000
  },
  "HourlyDashboardStatuses" : {
    "Remaining" : 999999999,
    "Max" : 999999999
  },
  "HourlySyncReportRuns" : {
    "Remaining" : 500,
    "Max" : 500
  },
  "HourlyTimeBasedWorkflow" : {
    "Remaining" : 50,
    "Max" : 50
  },
  "MassEmail" : {
    "Remaining" : 10,
    "Max" : 10
  },
  "SingleEmail" : {
    "Remaining" : 15,
    "Max" : 15
  },
  "StreamingApiConcurrentClients" : {
    "Remaining" : 20,
    "Max" : 20
  }
}`